# How does Elastic Beanstalk work behind the scenes for Django?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

For running django applications locally I can do

```
django-admin startproject djangotest
python djangotest/manage.py runserver
```

and the sample webpage shows up at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

However, when I deploy this to EB with

```
eb deploy
```

It just magically works. My question is does EB runs the command `python djangotest/manage.py runserver` on the EC2 server after `eb deploy` by default? What are the list of commands that EB executes to get the webpage working? What if I want it to run with different flags like `python djangotest/manage.py runserver --nostatic` is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't just magically work. You have to configure Django for Elastic Beanstalk, as described in [the EB documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-configure-for-eb): you provide a configuration file which points to the WSGI module.

In any case, it wouldn't use runserver, as the development server is absolutely not for production use.

Comment: 1. Is there a way to "run" the WSGI module locally to simulate a production environment? 2. Is there a way to run with ASGI (specifically daphne) on EB instead of WSGI?

Comment: Well all the ways of running Django - including the dev server - use the wsgi module, it's just a matter of what server you put in front of it. I don't know what EB uses, it might be something internal to Amazon.